# Immutablejs: How to deserialise a complex JS object

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

If I receive data from a server in plain JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "f223dc3c-946f-4da3-8e77-e8c1fe4d241b": {
        "name": "Dave",
        "age": 16,
        "jobs": [{
            "description": "Sweep the floor",
            "difficulty": 4
        },{
            "description": "Iron the washing",
            "difficulty": 6
        }]
    },
    "84af889a-8fc9-499b-a6ea-97e7a483130c": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Do I need to loop through all the `jobs` and convert them to `Map`s, then convert each object's `jobs` into a `List`, then the entire thing into a `Map`?

Or does ImmutableJS do this all recursively for me?

Comment: That's why I didn't say it was JSON - I said I have JSON that "looks like this"... apologies if it was too unclear for you.  I have updated it to *actual* JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`Immutable.fromJS()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) designed for exactly that.